# ExecuteScript - get the complete source website

Tags: javascript, delphi, webview2, execute-script

How to use ExecuteScript to get the complete page source - something like browser does with

`view-source: https//..any..web..page`

If I call ExecuteScript
`wbBrowser.ExecuteScript('document.documentElement.outerHTML')`
I only get what is displayed on the page. However, there are web pages that display data in a table and currently only display a portion of the records (e.g. 1-10 out of 1000).
By calling
`wbBrowser.ExecuteScript('document.documentElement.outerHTML')`
I only get the current 1-10, but the browser will display the complete data using `view-source: https//****)`.

Unfortunately, for data protection reasons, I can't show the source of the page. I hope I have described it clearly, sorry for the English

Comment: With view-source protocol a browser shows the content originally send from the server, that is rarely "complete data" shown on a page.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info, but for my purposes the data that the source returns is sufficient. So can we go back to my question of how to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read the data using view-source protocol instead of `http(s)`..?

Comment: yeah, I thought of that and tried it too ( instead of https I call view-source:https://----), of course it works, but I'm sure there's an easier way - something like DOCUMENT.ALL(*)
But I can't figure it out. I'm sure it works if view-source can do it

Answer (score 1):

`view-source` shows you the HTML source of an HTML document as it was sent from the server to the browser. Script like `document.documentElement.outerHTML` will give you an HTML serialization of the current state of the DOM which may not be the same as the original HTML source of the HTML document. There's no way in script (AFAIK) that can give you the original HTML source instead of the current state of the DOM.

In WebView2 if you want to see the actual content sent from the server you can use the [`CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.webresourceresponsereceived) to see the HTML source or the source of any other resource obtained from the network.